# Handsontable: loading cells dynamically - viewport events?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am loading the data via ajax so I don't have to load the unwanted cell until the user changes the view (scroll or keyboard navigation).

So far I have used the 'autoColumnSize' & 'autoRowSize' plugins to handle scrolling (code excerpt below) but it seems convoluted and doesn't handle keyboard navigation.

```
var colPlugin = hot.getPlugin('autoColumnSize');
var rowPlugin = hot.getPlugin('autoRowSize');
// ...plugin enabled here...
hot.addHook('afterScrollHorizontally', loadViewportData });
hot.addHook('afterScrollVertically', loadViewportData });

function loadViewportData () {
        var rowStart = rowPlugin.getFirstVisibleRow();
        var rowEnd = rowPlugin.getLastVisibleRow();
        var colStart = colPlugin.getFirstVisibleColumn();
        var colEnd = colPlugin.getLastVisibleColumn();
        // ...add +1/-1 to indexes to handle partially visible cells if within the table ...
        request =ajaxGetData(colStart, colEnd, rowStart, rowEnd);
        request.done(function (d) {
               // update table with the data...
        }
};
```

Is there an event in the core to handle changes to the viewport and would provide the view extents. Or should I use a different approach altogether?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you exactly want. Did you try `scrollViewportTo` ?